# Extracting items from 02 SelectListItem to show only unique Items in two selectlist

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, selectlist, selectlistitem

I have prepared two selectlistitems from the entity framework structure.

```cs
List<SelectListItem> out_file = _dbcontext.file_out
  .Where(x => x.section == _section && x.active == true)
  .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.file_id, Value = x.file_name })
  .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
  .ToList();

List<SelectListItem> fileid_list = _dbcontext.Master_table
  .Where(x => x.section == _section)
  .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.File_id, Value = x.File_name })
  .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
  .ToList();
```

Now I want to trim the `fileid_list` by removal of all the values which are already present in `out_file` list and display the same on the view page.

Please suggest me either the list preparation from scratch with using two tables in the entity framework environment or trimming of `fileid_list` from the another list.

```cs
List<SelectListItem> out_file = _dbcontext.file_out
  .Where(x => x.section == _section && x.active == true)
  .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.file_id, Value = x.file_name })
  .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
  .ToList();

List<SelectListItem> fileid_list = _dbcontext.Master_table
  .Where(x => x.section == _section)
  .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.File_id, Value = x.File_name })
  .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: You may try this:var targetsellist = (
    from sel2item in sellist2 
    where !sellist1.Any(sel1item => sel1item.Text == sel2item.Text && sel1item.Value == sel2item.Value) 
    select sel2item
  ).ToList();